# Android Getting deep JSON objects from Facebook GraphRequest

Tags: android, json, facebook

I'm using Facebook's Graph API and I'm trying to get deeper JSON objects than the surface ones.  How can I do this properly?

The JSON object looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": "#############",
    "name": "Page Name",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/76818_139533536097297_144033_n.jpg?oh=9caa264df8b15feb6ecdjeajks9d43ee05bc22&oe=5750EE78"
        }
    }
}
```

(The URL is not a real URL for this example)

I have tried this:

```
new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            facebook_name.setText("Logged in as " + object.optString("name"));
            try {
                JSONArray pictureArray = object.getJSONArray("picture");
                for (int i = 0; i < pictureArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject picture = pictureArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray pictureDataArray = picture.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int j = 0; j < pictureDataArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject pictureData = pictureDataArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String pictureDataURL = pictureData.optString("url");
                        Log.d("*******************", pictureDataURL);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

But I'm not getting my `Log.d` back.  Am I traversing this incorrectly?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.  I just need to keep stringing on `.getJSONObject()` to keep going down lower to find what I'm looking for:

```
String pictureURL = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
```

Comment: It's better to use GSON or Retrofit to convert JSON response into Java classes.

Comment: @yueyueqi, could you please explain why it would be better? This is the simplest approach I've found. But I'd like to know why it would be better. Thanks

Comment: Because it will do JSON parsing for you, like handling those JSONArray/JSONObjects. And what you need to do is to define Java classes and focus on logic.